# Disable click from registering on parent li after child ul is clicked

Tags: javascript

```
var treeview = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview");
var submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview ul");
for (var i=0; i<treeview.length; i++;) {
    treeview[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("menu-open");
    e.stoppropagation();
});
```

The sub menu (treeview-menu) opens when there is a click on li but if the child ul links are click it closes the menu since click gets registered.

```
<li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
          </ul>
   </li>
```

my failed attempt as below :

```
var treeview = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview");
var submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview ul");
for (var i=0; i<treeview.length; i++) {
    treeview[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("menu-open");
    e.stoppropagation();
    submenu[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        e.stoppropagation();
    })
});
```

Comment: It is `stopPropagation` (capital P), not `stoppropagation`.

Comment: Changed it, still deosnt work. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>`

Comment: Well, this error is thrown because you use the same `i` variable for both of the lists, but they are totally different lists with unrelated indices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent underlying div onclick event to trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656694/prevent-underlying-div-onclick-event-to-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
    var treeview = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview");
    var submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".treeview ul");
    for (var i=0; i<treeview.length; i++) {
        treeview[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("menu-open");
    for (var x=0; x<treeview.length; x++){  
        submenu[x].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
      }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- The spelling of `stopPropagation` is wrong
- Unclosed brace, mostly because the indentation is off
- The inner event handler references an `i` that has already passed beyond the length of the `treeview` list. Be aware that the loop has finished before any clicking happens. So inside a click handler `i` is not related to a certain iteration of the loop. You can solve this with giving `i` block scope (using `let`)
- The inner event handler references an `e` object that belongs to another event, as you did not define it as parameter
- You assume that every `.treeview` has exactly one `ul` child, otherwise the index of related sub menus will not correspond.

Apart from the last point, the following works in your particular example:

```
for (let i=0; i<treeview.length; i++) { // block scope
    treeview[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.classList.toggle("menu-open");
        e.stopPropagation(); // Spelling!
        submenu[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { // <-- pass e
            e.stopPropagation(); // Spelling!
        });
    });
} // Fix brace
```

However, because `.treeview` elements might in theory have 0 or more than 1 child `ul`, the above solution is not generic enough. I would even suggest to only capture clicks on the `.treeview > a` element, and then you don't even have this propagation issue:

```js
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll(".treeview > a")) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.parentNode.classList.toggle("menu-open");
    });
}
```

```css
.menu-open > ul.treeview-menu { display: block }
.treeview > ul { display: none }
```

```html
<li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```